# Chatter posts - customise layout

Tags: chatter, page-layout

Is there an option to roll-up or hide individual Chatter posts? For example in my Chatter feed, I see chatter posts on cases I work on, however, when I have responded to a chatter post on a case, I would like to roll-it up in my feed, is there a setting for this functionality? From the drop down on the post, I see BookMarks | Topics | Delete but nothing for Hide or Roll -up.

Answer (score 3):

**Chatter Tab**

This functionality does not currently exist on the Chatter tab inside Salesforce. When you load up Chatter, you may see Chatter thread that has additional comments on it (that get rolled up by default).

[image: Collapsed Comments Internal]

However, once that is expanded, you can not collapse it again without a page refresh.

[image: All Comments Internal]

---

**Chatter Desktop**

With that said, you could use [Chatter Desktop](http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/downloadchatterdesktop.jsp) which does allow you collapse and uncollapse different Chatter posts and their comments.

By default it will display collapsed.

[image]

But you can then Hide Comments as well

[image]

---

**Salesforce1**

If you absolutely must stay in the browser, you could technically use Salesforce1 as well. There are a few things you have to do to get it to work properly, but it will allow you to view just the main post.

[image]

It will then transition to a different pane when you want to view the comments.

[image]

If you want to go this route, I wrote up an article on [Working with Salesforce1 on the Desktop](http://jessealtman.com/2013/12/working-with-salesforce1-on-the-desktop/) you may find useful.